# HTML button is showing behind a Three.js background until I open Dev Tools

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

I'm busy doing an assignment for university making a 3D scene using Three.js. One of the requirements is to include a button, that when clicked, makes one of my 3 vehicle objects drive

The issue I'm experiencing is that I cannot see my button when my page loads. What happens is I'll see the button for a second or so with a white page, and then I'm assuming my JavaScript loads in and covers the button. I'm trying to bring this button to the foreground as I can see that it is there when using the inspect dev tool

This brings me to the part I don't understand, as soon as I open or close the Dev Tool command, my button will then appear at the bottom of the page and stay there. I am using the VS Code live server extension with Brave as my default browser this opens in.

Below is some of the code I think is necessary:

```
<style>
    * { box-sizing: border-box }
    #container { width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 50px) }
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #btnDrive { height: 40px; width: 25%; float: left; margin: 10px 0 0; background-color: orange; color: black; }
</style>

<body onLoad="onLoad()"> 
<div id="container"></div>
<button id="btnDrive" type="button">Drive Car</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/102/three.js"></script>
<script>
function onLoad() 
{
    const container = document.getElementById('container');
    const width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight;
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true });
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    renderer.setClearColor(0x87ceeb);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

......</script></body>}
```

Comment: Does setting the zIndex on your button help?.

Comment: Hi Keith, I have tried z-index with multiple different parameters (unset, initial, inherit, auto, -1, 1, -10, 10, -1000, 1000) and it did not assist, I can still only see the button for about a second when loading the page or after I open/close the dev tools

Comment: Not sure, I'm normally able to place HTML elements on top of a three.js canvas without issues.  What browser are you seeing this on?,  are you able to knock up a snippet showing the issue?.

Comment: Oh, hang on a minute you have `overflow: hidden;` on your body, but no `position: absolute` on your button, I believe that will be your issue.  So your button is likely off screen as that would be the normal flow, seen as you have set the canvas height to be the same as the window height.

Comment: @Keith I have added the project to my [GitHub](https://github.com/josh-bristow/python-projects/tree/main/University%20Projects/Computer%20Graphics)  so you can see the full code. I've tried on both Brave and Chrome and the same thing happens

Comment: Just a note: z-index only applies to _positioned_ elements. So the elements that you wish to stack using z-index must all have a `position` style, even if the value is `position: relative;`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @TheJim01 and @Keith, I made the below changes in my Style section and this solved my issue, the button now appears on top of my Three.js background

```
<style>
    * { box-sizing: border-box }
    #container { width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 50px); position: fixed; }
    body {
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    #btnDrive { height: 40px; width: auto; float: left; margin: 10px 0 0; background-color: orange; color: black; position: relative} 
</style>
```